# Tomcat crashes due to native code in JDK for malloc_consolidate

Tags: java, tomcat

The tomcat server in production crashes often while JavaThread "Finalizer" runs in the JVM with hs_err_pid below.

Also, the error comes from Java native code for malloc_consolidate inside libc.so.

```
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libc.so.6+0x75f85]  malloc_consolidate+0xf5
#
---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00007f2c6018f000):  JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=11112, stack(0x00007f2c3f1f2000,0x00007f2c3f2f3000)]


Stack: [0x00007f2c3f1f2000,0x00007f2c3f2f3000],  sp=0x00007f2c3f2f13e0,  free space=1020k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [libc.so.6+0x75f85]  malloc_consolidate+0xf5

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
J 2177  java.util.zip.Inflater.end(J)V (0 bytes) @ 0x00007f2c50e3d301 [0x00007f2c50e3d2c0+0x41]
J 3502 C2 java.util.zip.ZipFile.close()V (223 bytes) @ 0x00007f2c514371c4 [0x00007f2c51436900+0x8c4]
J 7022 C2 java.util.zip.ZipFile.finalize()V (5 bytes) @ 0x00007f2c511b43e0 [0x00007f2c511b43a0+0x40]
J 11603% C2 java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run()V (55 bytes) @ 0x00007f2c528d6f78 [0x00007f2c528d6cc0+0x2b8]
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

Heap:
 PSYoungGen      total 2318848K, used 222178K [0x0000000720000000, 0x00000007c0000000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 2016256K, 5% used [0x0000000720000000,0x0000000726d4fbe0,0x000000079b100000)
  from space 302592K, 36% used [0x000000079b100000,0x00000007a1ca8fe0,0x00000007ad880000)
  to   space 289792K, 0% used [0x00000007ae500000,0x00000007ae500000,0x00000007c0000000)
 ParOldGen       total 2586624K, used 522596K [0x00000005e0000000, 0x000000067de00000, 0x0000000720000000)
  object space 2586624K, 20% used [0x00000005e0000000,0x00000005ffe59390,0x000000067de00000)
 Metaspace       used 148258K, capacity 154058K, committed 154200K, reserved 1183744K
  class space    used 18157K, capacity 19308K, committed 19328K, reserved 1048576K

Internal exceptions (10 events):
Event: 61.804 Thread 0x00007f2c2c0c6800 Exception <a 'java/io/IOException'> (0x0000000798129018) thrown at [/HUDSON3/workspace/8-2-build-linux-amd64/jdk8u121/8372/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp, line 709]
Event: 61.816 Thread 0x00007f2c2c0c6800 Exception <a 'java/io/IOException'> (0x0000000798304680) thrown at [/HUDSON3/workspace/8-2-build-linux-amd64/jdk8u121/8372/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp, line 709]
Event: 61.816 Thread 0x00007f2c2c0c6800 Exception <a 'java/io/IOException'> (0x0000000798305b90) thrown at [/HUDSON3/workspace/8-2-build-linux-amd64/jdk8u121/8372/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp, line 709]
Event: 62.015 Thread 0x00007f2c2c0bb800 Exception <a 'java/io/IOException'> (0x0000000720db4188) thrown at [/HUDSON3/workspace/8-2-build-linux-amd64/jdk8u121/8372/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp, line 709]
Event: 62.015 Thread 0x00007f2c2c0bb800 Exception <a 'java/io/IOException'> (0x0000000720db47e0) thrown at [/HUDSON3/workspace/8-2-build-linux-amd64/jdk8u121/8372/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp, line 709]
Event: 62.046 Thread 0x00007f2c2c0bb800 Exception <a 'java/io/IOException'> (0x0000000720dbc2f0) thrown at [/HUDSON3/workspace/8-2-build-linux-amd64/jdk8u121/8372/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp, line 709]
Event: 62.046 Thread 0x00007f2c2c0bb800 Exception <a 'java/io/IOException'> (0x0000000720dbd800) thrown at [/HUDSON3/workspace/8-2-build-linux-amd64/jdk8u121/8372/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp, line 709]
Event: 62.082 Thread 0x00007f2c606f8800 Exception <a 'java/lang/InternalError'> (0x0000000721cfe9b8) thrown at [/HUDSON3/workspace/8-2-build-linux-amd64/jdk8u121/8372/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp, line 735]
Event: 62.082 Thread 0x00007f2c606f8800 Exception <a 'java/lang/InternalError'> (0x0000000721cfeda8) thrown at [/HUDSON3/workspace/8-2-build-linux-amd64/jdk8u121/8372/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp, line 735]
Event: 62.082 Thread 0x00007f2c606f8800 Exception <a 'java/lang/InternalError'> (0x0000000721cfeda8) thrown at [/HUDSON3/workspace/8-2-build-linux-amd64/jdk8u121/8372/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp, line 1394]

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/tmp/heap -Djava.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort=true -Xms3072M -Xmx7680M -Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true
```

Comment: may i know which verison of java and tomcat you are using

Comment: Java : 1.8. update 121 and Tomcat  8.15

Comment: Tomcat 8.0.15 or  8.5.15 ?

Comment: And may i know which ide you are using ?

Comment: Tomcat is 8.0.15. IDE is IntelliJ but how does that matter

Answer (score 0):

-Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true should fix this issue, zip implementation is improved in JDK 9, The crash suggest that, during finalizer tries to close the file handle, it was still not released.
Upgrading JDK9 should avoid this issue - https://jdk9.java.net/download/

Comment: Thanks @Fairoz . I have alredy implemented the above flag but it does not helps. Also, waiting for JDK 9 to be production ready.

Comment: It will happen in July, meanwhile you can use 9 ea builds, available in https://jdk9.java.net/download/

Comment: Please share your feedback..:.

Comment: I tried using 1.9.ea138 update and ported code according to it. But after some time the version was upgraded to 152 and they have changed a lot in the JDK since 138. So, I was not able to port on 158 version with existing hibernate and spring versions. It will take a lot more than just jdk update.